# I have this sql query using knex, I am able to retrieve the records but it is not sorting correctly when chaining OrderByRaw

Tags: postgresql, query-builder, knex.js

I have this handler that calls this query builder.  I am able to retrieve the records, however they are not sorting correctly.

What i have:

```
getStuff(req) {
...

return (toSqlName, builder) => 
  builder.whereRaw(`${toSqlName('id')} = ANY(?::uuid[]`, [ids]).orderByRaw('username DESC')
}
```

Seems to work fine except the records coming back are not sorted.  I've tried chaining .orderBy('username', 'desc') as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.orderBy`:

```js
knex.select()
    .table('products')
    .orderBy('name', 'desc')
    .orderBy('id', 'asc')
```

Comment: I've tried and that doesnt work.  I suspect it has something to do with whereRaw and being inside a return statement.